# Unable to integrate Dialogflow CX Messenger Integration

Tags: dialogflow-es, dialogflow-cx

I am using dialogflow CX to develop agents and I would like to test the rich content media like buttons which is not possible in the Test Agent Simulator.

I am trying to integrate Dialogflow messenger but the enable button is grayed out. Image attached below

Any advice or help is appreciated!

[image: error]

Dialogflow API is enabled, and the credentials are created.

Comment: Did this [link1](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/cx/docs/concept/integration/dialogflow-messenger) and [link2](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/support/troubleshooting?agent=cx&category=any) will help you? And could you please elaborate on your issue also ?

Comment: Have you enabled a billing account in your project? Dialogflow messenger requests are billed and the button is greyed out of billing is not set up for your project.